# Eclipse Custom Variable for Java Code Templates

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

How do you add a new variable to be inserted into a Java code template. How do I add a variable to the list in Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates->Code->New Java Files->Edit->Insert Variable... ?

Currently my new files get created with:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}
${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

I'd like them to get created with something like:

```
${begin_filecomment}
${package_declaration}
${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
${end_filecomment}
```

where begin_filecomment and end_filecomment appear in the Insert Variable list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the list of "variables" is generated by Eclipse and there is no way to add a new template variable.

What do you want `${begin_filecomment}` and `${end_filecomment}` to be? Just type the content into the Edit box - there is nothing that says you cannot put static content in there.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can indeed add a variable to this list.  See the extension point called

org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates

and you'll find out how.

Comment: This only seems to work for `Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates`, not for `Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates` templates.

Answer (score 8):

To contribute a new variable, you need to create a plugin and implement the org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates extension-point.

You have to contribute a sub-class of org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.TemplateVariableResolver that will implement the various resolve methods to resolve the placeholder to your desired value(s).

See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors_templates.html) for help on the extension point and an example that contributes the ant variables.

As matt b says, you often just need to define your text as boilerplate, so implementing a variable for that is overkill.

Comment: This only seems to work for `Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates`, not for `Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code Templates` templates.

Answer (score 4):

and see http://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/use-maven-artifact-version-in-eclipse-templates/

Answer (score 3):

I didn't try it, but maybe you could edit the template files in the JDT jar:

```
eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui_*.jar\templates\
```

Answer (score 3):

See
http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/use-your-own-variable-in-eclipse-code-templates/

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the conversation, I also wanted to insert a custom variable into a template. My issue was that I wanted to insert a variable from jsp/jstl definition inside the template.

(I.E. `<c:set var="myVariable" value="${requestScope.variableName}" />`)

This apparently caused some issues because templates already use the `${}` syntax to help resolve its own variables.

So simple solution I included an additional `$` to the pattern in the template. Two `$$` signs resolves it to a single `$` sign, hence giving me exactly what I wanted. Hopefully this helps the poster or someone with similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my note.
I hope it helps you.

My Eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)

- Add GlobalTemplateVariables

  Jar : org.eclipse.text.jar

  1. org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.GlobalTemplateVariables

  ```
    public static class MyID extends SimpleTemplateVariableResolver {
        private static String value = System.getProperty("myID");

        public MyID() {
            super("myID", TextTemplateMessages.getString("GlobalVariables.variable.description.myID")); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        }

        @Override
        protected String resolve(TemplateContext context) {
            if (value == null) {
                return TextTemplateMessages.getString("GlobalVariables.variable.description.myID");
            }
            return value; // $NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
  ```

  2. org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.TextTemplateMessageg.properties

  ```
  # global variables
  GlobalVariables.variable.description.myid=myID
  ```
- Java

  1. Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation.jar

  - org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.manipulation.CodeTemplateContextType.java

    ```
    public CodeTemplateContextType(String contextName) {
        super(contextName);

        fIsComment= false;

        // global
        addResolver(new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver(new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver(new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver(new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver(new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver(new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
        addResolver(new Todo());
    ```

  2. Java -> Editor -> Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation.jar

     - org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.template.java.AbstractJavaContextTypeCore.java

     ```
       public void initializeContextTypeResolvers() {
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Cursor());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.WordSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Selection("line_selection", JavaTemplateMessages.CompilationUnitContextType_variable_description_line_selection));
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
     ```
- JSP

  1. Web -> JSP Files -> Editor -> Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.jar

     - org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.templates.TemplateContextTypeJSP.java

     ```
       public TemplateContextTypeJSP() {
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Cursor());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.LineSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.WordSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
     ```
- JavaScript

  1. Web -> Client-side JavaScript -> Code Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.jar

     - org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.template.java.CodeTemplateContextType.java

     ```
       public CodeTemplateContextType(String contextName) {
        super(contextName);
        this.fIsComment = false;
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
        addResolver(new Todo());
     ```
  2. Web -> Client-side JavaScript -> Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.jar

     - org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.corext.template.java.JavaContextType.java

     ```
       public JavaContextType() {
        super("javaScript");
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Cursor());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.WordSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.LineSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
     ```
- HTML

  1. Web -> HTML Files -> Ediotr -> Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.jar

     - org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.internal.templates.TemplateContextTypeHTML.java

     ```
       public TemplateContextTypeHTML() {
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Cursor());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.LineSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.WordSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new EncodingTemplateVariableResolverHTML());
     ```
- CSS

  1. Web -> CSS Files -> Ediotr -> Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.wst.css.ui.jar

     - org.eclipse.wst.css.ui.internal.templates.TemplateContextTypeCSS.java

     ```
       public TemplateContextTypeCSS() {
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Cursor());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.LineSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.WordSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new EncodingTemplateVariableResolverCSS());
     ```
- XML

  1. XML -> XML Files -> Ediotr -> Templates

     Jar : org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.jar

     - org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.templates.TemplateContextTypeXML.java

     ```
       public TemplateContextTypeXML() {
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Cursor());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Date());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Dollar());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.LineSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Time());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.User());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.WordSelection());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.Year());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new GlobalTemplateVariables.MyID());
        addResolver((TemplateVariableResolver)new EncodingTemplateVariableResolverXML());
     ```

Then add custom-variable in eclipse.ini after -vmargs

```
-DmyID=7777
```

Then you can use it in your templates