# In Eclipse, how do I change the default modifiers in the class/type template?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, templates

Eclipse's default template for new types (Window > Preferences > Code Style > Code Templates > New Java Files) looks like this:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

Creating a new class, it'll look something like this:

```
package pkg;

import blah.blah;

public class FileName {
    // Class is accessible to everyone, and can be inherited 
}
```

Now, I'm fervent in my belief that access should be as restricted as possible, and inheritance should be forbidden unless explicitly permitted, so I'd like to change the `${type_declaration}` to declare all classes as `final` rather than `public`:

```
package pkg;

import blah.blah;

final class FileName {
    // Class is only accessible in package, and can't be inherited
}
```

That seems easier said than done. The only thing I've found googling is a [2004 question on Eclipse's mailing list](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg25600.html) which was unanswered.

So, the question in short: **How can I change the default class/type modifiers in Eclipse?**

I'm using Eclipse Galileo (3.5) if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible. The `${type_declaration}` is internal stuff.

What you can do is to click everytime the final checkbox in the "New Java Class"-Dialog. But that's not something you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the appropriate access modifier when creating the new class with the New Class Wizard.

[New Java Class Wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-class.htm)

Comment: That's what I do today. The thing is that it doesn't remember my choice, so I forget to do it every now and then.

Comment: @gustafc You can let Checkstyle warn you if you forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i think there isn't any cool answer, so what about that "hack"?

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
import invalid;/* ${type_declaration} */

final class ${type_name} { }
```

If you now hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to organize imports, the old type declaration disappears. You could also add organize imports to save action to automate.

I know it's bad, but it does what you want.

Comment: Well... interesting thought. Unfortunately, it then declares everything as `final class`, including interfaces, enums, etc, and it misses any superclasses/interfaces I declare in the wizard. I also have to include the `${type_declaration}` in a comment as you can't save the template without it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you?

```
  eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui_*.jar\templates\
```

[Eclipse custom variable for java code templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350600/eclipse-custom-variable-for-java-code-templates)

Comment: Not really, it just seems to be where eclipse picks up the templates. The `${type_declaration}` isn't there. I'm beginning to suspect it's generated rather than declared.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround:

Edit the template:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}   
final class ${type_name} {

    /* ${type_declaration} //delete */

    /** 
     * @see {@link Object#toString()}
     * @return String representation of this instance. 
     */
    public String toString() {
        return "some impl";
    }

}
```

Comment out the ${type_declaration} because it is required.  You have comment to delete, but requirement is achieved.  Sorry if this is a 2 year old thread, but to me it is still relevant.