# Is there a Eclipse template variable for short version of enclosing type name

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I would like to create a constructor template in Eclipse for Java classes. I've got a version that works for most classes. Although it doesn't work for classes nested in other classes. (see class `Inner` below) How do I get the short version of the class name?

#### Not working template

```
public ${newType:enclosing_type}() {
    ${cursor}
}
```

#### Example failing class

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
        // Current template expands to the following
        public Outer.Inner() {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I checked on Indigo. You can't. Your only option, as far as i know, is to introduce a new variable in template list in order to get inner class name without the outer class(es) name(s).

If you accept the effort of writing a bit of code (read plugin) to get your goal, you can start from:

- http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/use-your-own-variable-in-eclipse-code-templates/
- [How to pass parameter into code-template in eclipse-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577505/how-to-pass-parameter-into-code-template-in-eclipse-plugin)
- [Eclipse Custom Variable for Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350600/eclipse-custom-variable-for-java-code-templates?rq=1)

or if you are lazy like me, you can start downloading this project: https://github.com/aabeling/template-variables and customizing it as your needs.